# Error en referencias a librerías de JQuery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, librería

Tengo una web diseñada con Bootstrap 4, y funcionando correctamente, pero si le intento cambiar el enlace de referencia a los scripts de externos a local, de la siguiente manera:

1.- Enlace original externo que hace funcionar todo bien:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

2.- Enlace nuevo en local que me empieza a dar errores:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

El error que me da es al pulsar sobre un menu desplegable y es el siguiente error capturado por consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las librerias parece que las carga bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Me podéis ayudar? ¿Como hago para referenciar correctamente dicha librería?
Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Jose tu proyecto lo tienes corriendo en la partición raíz o no? podrías hacer un pwd o indicarme la ruta en la que tienes tu proyecto?

Comment: No lo tengo en el raíz, esta en "C:\desarrollo\coursera\" pero te remarco que con el fichero externo si que funciona perfectamente y el resto de scripts que carga si que funcionan bien, ya sean el popper, bootstrap así como los CSS y JS propios.

Comment: @Jose Si la local es 3.5.0 hay un error que afecta a varios plugins de jquery. Hasta que lo  resuelvan vuelva a la 3.4.1. Si te sirvió hago una respuesta más elaborada del porque. ( No es que carguen mal, las librerías son correctas,pero dentro de ellas hay un par de plugins que las hacen fallar) EDITO:-> Técnicamente en la versión 3.5.1 han fixeado el bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a la información que has compartido en los comentarios considero que estas realizando mal la referencia a la librería de forma local:

```
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Tus node modules son parte de tu proyecto, al intentar cargalos lo que estas haciendo con la ruta `/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js` es salirte de tu proyecto e ir a buscar jquery a la ruta `C:\`.

Lo único que debes hacer es eliminar la `/` al inicio, esto hara que no te salgas de tu proyecto y se busque la librería en tu carpeta actual que como tu comentas es `C:\desarrollo\coursera\` de esta manera utilizarás la ruta relativa y buscaras los scripts en la carpeta de tu proyecto.

Tu ruta quedaría:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Espero te sea útil, saludos.

Comment: No es por eso, he quitado la barra del inicio, tal como aparece en el código que he puesto y sigue fallando, de hecho las otras dos librerías las carga correctamente con la barra incluida.

Comment: Puedes mostrar una captura de las herramientas de desarrollo y especificamente de la parte de Network? Para verificar que todos tus archivos cargan correctamente? Si tienes dudas de como hacerlo te dejo este link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network estando en Network debes recargar.

Comment: Si, estaban mal las rutas, si que fallaban las cargas de scripts por ese detalle de la barra inicial, al revisarlo con otro navegador me han salido los fallos a todos los ficheros por lo mismo que Chrome no mostraba. Pero aun así el mismo fallo sigue ocurriendo despues de corregidas las rutas y si pongo el enlace externo funciona.

Comment: Corregir las rutas mas el actualizar la version del JQuery, ya que la 3.5.0 tenia algunos fallos, a la 3.5.1. ha solucionado el problema. Gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: Un gusto @Jose has sido muy paciente para compartir los detalles solicitados.

Comment: Por favor, @allexiusw, deja tu respuesta de las barras de inicio como la ultima y borra las ediciones posteriores, fueron la que me salvaron del error, eso junto a la actualizacion a JQuery 3.5.1.Gracias. No es necesario un downgrade para JQuery solamente haciendo: npm install JQuery se soluciono todo junto a la correccion de las barrar iniciales.

Comment: Excelente ahoríta hago el cambio.

Answer (score 0):

Debes asegurarte que el script que sustituye en local al que haces referencia sea la misma versión, con los mismos contenidos... y es probable que, dependiendo de lo que esté haciendo tu script necesites también indicarle el `crossorigin="anonymous"`

Comment: El codigo externo es la version 3.4.1 y el local es la 3.5.0, si es una version superior se supone que no hay problema, ¿noooooo?. Por otro lado, le he colocado el crossorigin y sigue fallando. Gracias por interesarte.